# Qt error: qt.qpa.fonts: Unable to open default EUDC font: "C:\\WINDOWS\\FONTS\\EUDC.TTE"

Tags: python, pyside2, pyside6

Every time I run a PySide2/6 app I get the following error printed in terminal:

```
qt.qpa.fonts: Unable to open default EUDC font: "C:\\WINDOWS\\FONTS\\EUDC.TTE"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there was a wrong registry configuration of my PC and Qt tried to find a font called EUDC.TTF font, which did not exist.
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1620

Comment: The question says .TTE, not .TTF. I got the same error message and it said .TTE too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this [comment](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1620?focusedCommentId=575418&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-575418) from this [bugreport](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1620) helped:

> I have fixed it editing  \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\EUDC\1252 (1252 is the code of the latin alphabet) "SystemDefaultEUDCFont" key value to "C:\Windows\Fonts\seguibli.TTF" (for Segoe UI font) which it seems like it is the default windows font.